# Is freeing a dynamically allocated array same as freeing a linked list?

Tags: c, free

Suppose I have a struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct node{
char **word_ptrs;
int value;
struct node *next;
} Node;
```

and I have dynamically allocated spaces for the linked list, as well as the word_ptrs within this struct.

For example:

```
Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node)); // not important, what I care is not this node.
head->word_ptrs = malloc(10 * sizeof(Node)); // I care about this.
```

My question is: I know how to free the linked list, but I feel confused when I try to free the dynamically allocated array. When I try to free the array above, should I just directly free the entire array? Or I should go to free every single char * within that array?

Thanks.

Comment: That depends on where those pointers came from. If they point to dynamically allocated memory, you must. If they don't, you mustn't.

Comment: in the above case it will depend on how you have allocated the memory, this is the pointer to a pointer concept. so usually first you have to allocate head->word_ptrs = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *)); this will allocate number of rows and then you have to allocate for each row head->word_ptrs[i] = malloc(<any_size> * sizeof(char));. i can be till 9, after this you can store the string information to this. and while freeing you have to free word_ptrs[i] first and then free word_ptrs. so you have to free all the allocated address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only pass to `free` what was returned from `malloc`.

In this case, you make one allocation for an array of `char *`, so you do a single `free` to clean it up.  Also, the amount of space you're allocating is `10 * sizeof(Node)`, but it should be `10 * sizeof(char *)`.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on where those pointers came from, and who owns them.

If they were dynamically allocated and the node owns them, then you should free them before freeing the array.
If they were dynamically allocated but owned elsewhere, their respective owners should free them later.
If they were not dynamically allocated, you mustn't free them at all.
If you have a combination of the three, you're in trouble.

You should also allocate it with `sizeof(char*)`, or `sizeof(*head->word_ptrs)`, not `sizeof(Node)`.

Although, if the size is always ten, you might as well use an array:

```
typedef struct node{
    char *word_ptrs[10];
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} Node;
```

Comment: Ownership is the key here. Ownership explicitly defines the responsibility for freeing the memory block and is defined via so-called "interface contracts".